# Citrix Metaframe/RD - screen refresh weirdness

Tags: remote-desktop, citrix

I access a clients W2003 machine (XEN Virtualization) using RD over Citrix Metaframe. Everything used to be fine. Some weeks ago things turned bad ! All is well initially but after, say, 5 minutes the screen will stop refreshing.

Rather weirdly you can then still proceed in a way as you can make the screen refresh by getting the RD window to go through a restore/maximise cycle (this is only possible using the ALT-BREAK shortcut as everything else is locked up). This then allows you to proceed by typing something and going ALT-BREAK to see the results. Using menus is just not possible at all.

There's some indications that clearing the java cache between sessions helps. Also that the lockup happens more quickly if you make the 'lots of stuff happen' on the screen - for instance if you do a directory listing of a big directory then often that will cause the lockup to occur. Similary opening a dense Excel workbook and then scrolling it will cause the lockup to occur.

Any Metaframe veterans out there who recognise these symptoms ? I'd be very grateful as it's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, screen refreshing issues are almost always Citrix\XenApp client related and upgrading to the latest client resolves them all. Can you upgrade to a newer client? I know XenApp Windows client is up to 11.2

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for delay in replying. I'm interested in doing what you say but because I'm using a browser (+Java) based access method I'm not sure how to upgrade the client as such . Is there a way ? Perhaps it would help if I pointed out that when I use IE to access I get the option to use ActiveX or Java but I've never managed to persuade it to use the ActiveX (I'm guessing this is due to my not running as an Administrator). Sorry to be so dim but any further help would be appreciated.

Comment: go here for the latest versions of all Citrix clients: http://www.citrix.com/English/ss/downloads/results.asp?productID=186&c1=sot2755

But to install the Windows client, yes, you probably need to be a local admin. not sure about that though.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you're connecting via RD over Citrix Metaframe, what do you mean? Are you using the Citrix client or the RDP client? What does the java cache have to do with it? Have you tried flushing the Citrix and RDP bitmap caches?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for delay in replying. To (try to) answer your questions: (A) I've got a URL I visit in my browser and this throws up a web page labelled 'Citrix Metaframe Secure Access Manager' - after various log ons, click throughs etc I get a remote desktop session starting on the target server (B) I think I'm using RD tunnelled through the Citrix client (C) Java Cache - sys admin said it might help (D) Haven't flushed two caches you mention - can you tell me how ?